# How to map enum to enum with the same keys

Tags: java, enums, mapping

How to map enum to enum with the same keys in Java.
For example..

```
public enum FirstEnum {
 A, B
} 

public enum ScndEnum {
 A, B, C
}
```

I couldnt find good solution

Comment: What map are you expecting from those enums?

Comment: I want to achieve two-way mapping

Comment: If ScndEnum to FirstEnum from type C then null

Comment: `assert ScndEnum.A == ScndEnum.valueOf(FirstEnum.A.name())`

Comment: I meant if that enums were in the objects. Is exists quick solution? I made map with keys as id and value as enum value and initialize it in static block, then i get instance of selected enum by id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't map directly from one enum type to another, but you can use the value of `name()` and map it using `valueOf()`. Both of these methods come with all enum classes:

```
ScndEnum aToA = ScndEnum.valueOf(FirstEnum.A.name());
```

And if you want to make that generic:

```
private static <E extends Enum<E>, F extends Enum<F>> 
    F mapEnum(E enum1, Class<F> enum2Class) {

    return Enum.valueOf(enum2Class, enum1.name());
}
```

Which you can call using something like

```
ScndEnum b = mapEnum(FirstEnum.B, ScndEnum.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Sharing objects between enums does not really make sense, given the definition of enums in Java.

Perhaps the solution for you is a collection of enums, such as [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) ([key-value pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute%E2%80%93value_pair)) where the key type is of one enum class and the value type is of another enum class.

```
Map< Animal , Food > feeding = 
    Map.of
    (
        DOG , MEAT ,
        CAT , MEAT ,
        BIRD , SEED ,
        BAT , FRUIT
    )
;
```

## An enum is a data type

An enum in Java is a class for which instances are named at compile-time, are automatically instantiated at run-time, and cannot be re-assigned. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Examples:

```
enum Animal { DOG , CAT , BIRD , BAT ; }

enum Flavor { VANILLA , CHOCOLATE , LAVENDER , LEMON ; }
```

Each name within the enum will be assigned an object, an instance of that enum’s class. In the examples above, `DOG` constant holds an `Animal` object, while `LEMON` constant holds a `Flavor` object.

Using an enum in Java makes sense when you have a specific collection of instances that are known at compile-time and are unchanged at runtime. This means you cannot call `new Animal()` in our example above. Four new `Animal` objects were automatically instantiated and assigned to each of the variable names when the class first loaded. No more `Animal` objects can be instantiated nor discarded after that enum class loads.

### No sharing between enums

So your question does not really make sense, given the definition of an enum. Objects of one enum are not shared with another enum.

## Collections

Perhaps what you are looking for is a *collection* of enum objects.

### `Set`

For example, here we use the implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) that is highly optimized for holding enum objects: [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html).

```
Set< Animal > furryPets = EnumSet.of( DOG , CAT ) ;
Set< Animal > flyingAnimals = EnumSet.of( BIRD , BAT ) ;
Set< Animal > featheredFlyingAnimals = flyingAnimals.clone().remove( BAT ) ;
```

### `Map`

You mentioned wanting a two-way mapping. So perhaps what you want is a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) to track one enum as a key and another enum as a value. The `EnumMap` class is highly-optimized for when your key is an enum.

As an example, let's add another enum.

```
enum Food { MEAT , SEED , FRUIT ; }
```

Map an animal to its type of food.

```
Map< Animal , Food > feeding = new EnumMap<>( Animal.class ) ;
feeding.put( DOG , MEAT ) ;
feeding.put( CAT , MEAT ) ;
feeding.put( BIRD , SEED ) ;
feeding.put( BAT , FRUIT ) ;
```

Retrieve the type of food to feed to bats.

```
Food foodForBats = feeding.get( BAT ) ;
```

## Member variable

An enum in Java is a special kind of class, but still a class. So an enum can have member fields, constructors, and accessor methods, just like regular Java classes.

So we could associate an `Animal` with its `Food` this way, by using member fields, constructors, and accessor methods.

```
enum Animal 
{
    DOG( Food.MEAT ) , 
    CAT( Food.MEAT ) , 
    BIRD( Food.SEED ) , 
    BAT( Food.FRUIT ) ;

    // Member fields.
    private Food food ;

    // Constructor.
    private Animal( Food foodArg ) 
    {
        this.food = foodArg ;
    }

    // Accessor "getter" method.
    public Food getFood() { return this.food ; }

}
```

As mentioned above, when the `Animal` class loads, its constructor is called four times, once per named constant. The specified `Food` object is passed to that constructor automatically, on your behalf. You can think of that line `DOG( Food.MEAT ) ,` as being an abbreviation of `public static final Animal DOG = new Animal( Food.MEAT) ;`.

Usage.

```
Food foodForBats = Animal.BAT.getFood() ;
```

Comment: I understand everything of above, however my question was caused by a strange use case in my company

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mapstruct library. It will automatically generate all needed code for you. You just need to wrote:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {
  FirstEnum map(SecondEnum e); 
}
```

And if values of both match, they will work by default (if not, you can create custom mapping).